# Red Turtle Video Stops Working After Upgrade

Tags: plone

I have a Plone site that I wanted to upgrade to Plone 4.2.4 from Plone 4.1.4 on a SLES linux server.  I did a snapshot backup to ensure my data was safe.  In the process of migration, there were no errors reported by the migration tool.  However, I noticed that videos stopped playing and just show black screens.  However, if I create a vanilla Plone site in the ZMI videos work fine.

In my eggs directory, I saw that two packages were updated.

- redturtle.video 0.7.3 became 1.0.0
- collective.rtvideo.youtube 0.1.0 became 0.2.0

I decided to revert to the older versions of the eggs and snapshotrestore from my backup.  I reinstalled the Red Turtle Video in portal_quickinstaller and cleared and rebuilt the catalog.  The videos still show up as black.

A similar thing happened to me when I accidentally got the newer version of collective.flowplayer.  My quick and dirty solution was to migrate my content to a new Plone site in the ZMI (copy and paste did the trick) and then I deleted the old site and renamed the new one.  Videos worked fine.

Has anyone else had this problem?  Any good solutions?

Comment: Hard to say what's going on, if the error is not reproducable. From what you report, I'd check possible conflicts with the editor in terms of link-integrity, link-resolution and html-filter-settings. Did your researches not return anyone else with a similar problem?

Comment: P.S.: I ment 'link-uid-resolving' not 'link-resolution'.

Comment: Really strange problem.

The first check I would implement is to test if the file content is still there and you can downalod it (xxx/at_download/file). Then check for JavaScript problem loading the video

Comment: Yeah, it is very strange!  And so far I can't seem to find anything.  I can confirm that at_download/file works and there is no corruption of the file when I download it.  I'm not sure how to check on link-uid-resolving.  Ida, could you point me in the right direction?  Also, I checked the JavaScript with FireBug and I get some errors, but I'm not quite sure what they mean.  "Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.  Assertion failed: ReaderArticleFinder aborting CandidateElement detection due to timeout
findCandidateElements"

Comment: And not sure if this helps, but the problem is with RTInternalVideo only and not a YouTube link (RTRemoteVideo).  But I did not have old YouTube content in there, only internal videos.  I can confirm that a new YouTube link works, but old and new RTInternalVideos do not.

Comment: So I looked into UID resolution.  Going to /Plone/resolveuid/[UID] went to the correct video, but it remains a black box.  So I've tried looking at differences in Javascript, CSS and KSS, but so far everything looks exactly the same.

Comment: I was able to recreate my error.  Download Plone 4.1.6 Unified Installer. Add redturtle.video = 0.7.3, collective.rtvideo.youtube = 0.1.0, collective.flowplayer = 3.0 to versions (and appropriate eggs/zcml slugs). Create a Plone site, add a Folder "Videos" and an RTInternalVideo called Test. Snapshot backup.  Then download Plone 4.2.4 Unified Installer. Add redturtle.video = 1.0.0, collective.rtvideo.youtube = 0.2.0, collective.flowplayer = 3.0 to my versions/eggs/zcml.  Copy snapshotbackups and blobstoragesnapshots/blobstorage.0.  Snapshotrestore.  The video no longer plays.

Answer (score 0):

An issue has been reported to the RedTurtle people with a step by step to recreate the bug:

https://github.com/RedTurtle/redturtle.video/issues/11